# C Showing prime numbers using For statement

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

I'm newly new to C programming , started about a week ago ! And i'm getting into loops i faced a problem writing a C program to show prime numbers less-than 100 . 
I'll share up the C code i've written and its output ! I'll wait for your help and your remarks about it

```
    #include<stdio.h>

    main(){

    int i,d,k;

    for( i=1 ; i<=100 ; i++ ){
        d=0;
        for( k=1 ; k<=i ; k++ ){
            if( i%k==0){
                d=d+1;
            }
        }
        if( d==1 ){
            printf("\n%d",i);
        }
    }

    getchar();
    getchar();

    }
```

Output:

```
  1
```

Thanx !

Comment: First remark: it doesn't work right.

Comment: basically you had a bad condition for prime numbers. you are counting number of factors of i.  you will at least have 1 and i itself as a factor.  And since you requires only 1 factor to be found, you will only find 1 that fulfill that requirement.   Instead of doing that, you can require that there is no factor of i between 2 and i/2.

Comment: You don't even have to go farther than sqrt(i). (Hint: you don't actually need `sqrt` in the loop condition if you do this)

Comment: This is actually one of those classical programming homework assignments. I suggest you analyze the correct algorithm shown here: http://www.programmingsimplified.com/c/source-code/c-program-for-prime-number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go...e.g 5 has to factors (1 and 5):

```
#include<stdio.h>

    main(){

    int i,d,k;

    for( i=1 ; i<=100 ; i++ ){
        d=0;
        for( k=1 ; k<=i ; k++ ){
            if( i%k==0){
                d=d+1;
            }
        }
        if( d==2 ){
            printf("\n%d",i);
        }
    }

    getchar();
    getchar();

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<stdio.h>

main(){

    int i,d,k;

    for( i=1 ; i<=100 ; i++ ){
        d=0;
        for( k=1 ; k<=i ; k++ ){
            if( i%k==0){
                d=d+1;
            }
        }
        if( d==1 ){
            printf("\n%d",i);
       }
   }

   getchar();
}
```

Comment: What is your reasoning for this code?  For the beginner to C programming, showing only code does not help. Edit your answer to include your reasoning that makes sense in the context of the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

Reading your algorithm with i=2.

```
 d=0
 k=1 : 2%1=0 so d=1
 k=2 : 2%1=0 so d=2
```

So 2 is not prime...Alrggg

There are many way to correct and make your code run faster.
Computing sqrt(i) for all i might be "costly" if i<100, but doing something similar from time to time would be a good trick...

More : no need to continue once a divisor is found
More : Eratosthenes is your friend...
More : smaller divisor is always prime...Store ?
More : look Wikipedia in fact... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test
Bye,

Francis

Comment: 2 is a prime number :D thnx though

Answer (score 0):

The main function should return an int: [What should main() return in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c).

Also, consider making a function to test if a number is prime. This is a cleaner approach, but I guess you did not learned them yet.

The algorithm you are using is not efficient at all. There are many ways to improve it.

To correct it, you should know that a prime number has 2 divisors (except 1, but it is not a prime): 1 and itself. Your second for loop checks for those 2, so a number is prime if d is 2, not 1.

Even if you are a beginner, you should try to improve this algorithm. Firstly, it is enough to check until sqrt(i) for divisors. Also, when you find a divisor, you can stop the loop. Also, as 1 is always a divisor, you may start the second loop with 2.

Comment: That's it ! the mistake was (d==1) i should've made (d==2) as a condition :D

Answer (score 0):

You are using `d` as a `flag` to detect if number was ever divisible during the inner for loop. Use it right. Whenever no is divisible, set flag to 1 indicating it's not prime. If flag is unaffected through the inner loop, means number is prime. You should also consider returning an `int` value from `main` function indicating exit status.

Change the code as follows.

```
  #include<stdio.h>
  main(){
     int i,d,k;
    for( i=2 ; i<=100 ; i++ ){
         d=0;
          for( k=2 ; k<i ; k++ ){
             if( i%k==0){
                d=1; //Set the flag to 1 indicating no. is not prime and break
                break;
             }
          }
         if( d==0){ //Means flag the was unaffected throughout the loop i.i. Prime
             printf("\n%d",i);
         }
     }
    getchar();
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: thnx ! the answer of Asim Awan was the closest :D

Comment: Closest.?? Closest to what.?